# Arc Land Error in Git

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I already used phabricator in past (nearly to 7 months ago). Now I'm trying to create a totally new instance to use.
I just the follow:

- Created a Git Branch
- Mapped to Phabricator
- Created some simple Task
- Cloned the repository to my machine
- Created, from master, one branch called T1
- Did a diff
- Reviewer accepted my diff
- Running arc land from branch T1

When I run arc land, I'm getting the following error:

```
$ arc land
Landing current branch 'T1'.
Switched to branch ←[1mmaster←[m. Updating branch...
Password for 'https://ricardovsilva@bitbucket.org':
Switched back to branch ←[1mT1←[m.
←[1mException←[m
Command failed with error #1!
COMMAND
git pull --ff-only --no-stat

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


(Run with `--trace` for a full exception trace.)
```

What I'm missing out? Why arc land is not working? Something changed in arc land command?

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, your master branch isn't setup to track the master branch on the remote.

You should run `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`.